# ChartJS horizontal chart display legend on each bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

I'm pretty new in ChartJS and I'm having a horizontal bar chart:

HTML

```
<canvas id="mybarChart"></canvas>
```

JavaScript:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("mybarChart");

    ctx.height = 300;

    var mybarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        responsive: true,
        data: data,
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    display: false,
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    display: false,
                    gridLines: {
                        color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                    },
                    barPercentage: 0.5,
                    categoryPercentage: 0.5
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

for which I'm trying to add the legend on each bar like [image: this] but right now it looks like [image: this]

I've tried adding

```
onAnimationComplete: function () {

            var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
            ctx.font = this.scale.font;
            ctx.fillStyle = this.scale.textColor
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";

            this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                dataset.points.forEach(function (points) {
                    ctx.fillText(points.value, points.x, points.y - 10);
                });
            })
        }
```

but still the same result. What am I doing wrong? 
I found something [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfvy12h9/) but the labels displayed on each bar are the ticks for Y axes. 
Is possible to add the legend on each bar and also keep the tooltip?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually several ways that you can achieve this.  For simplicity, I will just modify the example that you provided.

Keep in mind that this puts the label inside the bar.  You can easily modify this to place it outside, but you will have to add logic to make sure you don't overflow on the top of the chart or into other bars (not very simple logic).

Also, this approach requires that you have configured a label for each dataset (which is needed to drive the regular legend anyway).

Just put this in your `animation.onComplete` property.

```
function() {
  var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
  ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
  ctx.textAlign = 'left';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

  this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
      var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model,
          scale_max = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._yScale.maxHeight;
      left = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._xScale.left;
      offset = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._xScale.longestLabelWidth;
      ctx.fillStyle = '#444';
      var y_pos = model.y - 5;
      var label = model.label;
      // Make sure data value does not get overflown and hidden
      // when the bar's value is too close to max value of scale
      // Note: The y value is reverse, it counts from top down
      if ((scale_max - model.y) / scale_max >= 0.93)
        y_pos = model.y + 20;
      // ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, y_pos);

      if (dataset.data[i] > 0) {
        ctx.fillText(dataset.label, left + 10, model.y + 8);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jordanwillis/3v959m80/) (forked from the example you provided).

Comment: I want to keep the tooltip but when you hoover over a bar the labels on it disappear and it should not. It is possible to do this or better, just to add the value next to the label and disable the tooltip?

Comment: I've edited: ctx.fillText(dataset.label + ' ' + dataset.data[0], left + 10, model.y + 8); and it works perfectly

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: Just a few comments: I'd store `dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]` in a variable to avoid repetition, and `offset`, `y_pos` and `label` are not used, therefore I ended up removing much of the code, like `scale_max` and the first `if`.